# np.where select pixels that red value bigger than green value in an BGR image

Tags: python, numpy

It's my first time using np.where to select pixels from a bgr image, i have no idea how to select pixels that r>g from image by using np.where, I tried to do that by using codes like this:

```
bgr = cv2.imread('im.jpg')
bgr = np.where(bgr[1]>bgr[2],np.full_like(bgr,[255,255,255]),bgr)
cv2.imshow('result',bgr)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

but it seems didn't work. Can anybody help me?

Comment: you can use [boolean array indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing)

Comment: `where` is only as good as the condition array, here `bgr[1]>bgr[2]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want to make all pixels white where red exceeds green and retain the original colours elsewhere. If so, I find it clearer this way:

```
# Load image
im = cv2.imread('image.png')

# Make simple synonyms for red and green
R = im[...,2]
G = im[...,1]

# Make True/False Boolean of pixels where red exceeds green
MoreRedThanGreen = R > G

# Make the image white wherever it is more red than green
im[MoreRedThanGreen,:] = [255,255,255]

# Save result
cv2.imwrite('result.png', im)
```

That makes this start image:

[image]

into this:

[image]

---

**Note**: Read the colon (`:`) in this line as meaning *"all the channels"*:

```
im[MoreRedThanGreen,:] = [255,255,255]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that it doesn't work because RGB is the last dimension of your image. Rewrite the slicing in `np.where`. Something like that:

```py
bgr = cv2.imread('im.jpg')
print(bgr.shape)  # (h, w, 3)
bgr = np.where(bgr[..., 1:2] > bgr[..., 2:3],  # make sure that tensors are of shape 3
               np.full_like(bgr, 255), bgr)
cv2.imshow('result', bgr)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Note that the ellipsis `bgr[..., 1:2]` means `bgr[:, :, 1:2]` here.